# Java Link-list head cannot found

Tags: java, linked-list

Try to create an empty link list. To creating the empty list I create a inner class Node and made it static such that main class can access it.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Addtwo {
static class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node head;

    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
        // Constructor
    }

        public static void main (String args[])
        {
            /* Start with the empty list. */
            LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();

            llist.head = new Node(1);
            Node second = new Node(2);
            Node third = new Node(3);
            llist.head.next = second;
            second.next = third;
        }

    }
}
```

It cannot find the node head that I create within the inner class Node. How to solve this?

**Error:**

```
  Error   :(22, 22) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : variable head
  location: variable llist of type java.util.LinkedList
```

Comment: You're importing the JDK's LinkedList. Did you mean to use your own?

Comment: Why does every `Node` have its own `head`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to use the JDK's `LinkedList`, you don't need to manage the nodes of the list, this work is already implemented. You only need to do this:

```
LinkedList<Integer> llist = new LinkedList<Integer>();
llist.add(1);
llist.add(2);
llist.add(3);
```

And there is more functionality [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Second, if you want to implement your own linked list (I think this is what you want), you don´t need to use the JDK's LinkedList, you can start with this basic code:

```
public class Addtwo {
    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;

        Node(int d) {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Start with the empty list. */
            Node head = new Node(1);
            Node second = new Node(2);
            Node third = new Node(3);
            head.next = second;
            second.next = third;

            Node iterator = head;
            while (iterator != null) {
                System.out.println(iterator.data);
                iterator = iterator.next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: You don't need to store a head for each node. You probably need another class `LinkedListManager` to implement some methods and store the head and the tail of the list.